# SQL query, NOT IN returns an error

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello guys i got a little problem. So I got 2 tables robot_calls and invoices. I'm trying to get ID of an invoice which is not in ID of robot_calls.invoice_id. I get an error  `Unknown column in 'where clause`.

```
SELECT * FROM invoices where `desc`='Invoice from mr. Robot' NOT IN
(SELECT * FROM invoices where robot_calls.invoice_id=invoices.id)";
```

I'm not an sql expert, can someone enlight me please?

Cheers.

Comment: You can not use NOT IN this way. It should be like select  from tbl1 where id not in (select id from table2)

Comment: You select from invoices twice, but never from robot_calls...

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Formatted text please, not images.

Comment: Ahhh! Okay thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select a single `id` column from your `robot_calls` table to do this query: `WHERE invoice_id NOT IN (SELECT invoice_id FROM robot_calls)`

Another alternative to this query is to use existential quantifier:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices iv
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM robot_calls rc WHERE rc.invoice_id=iv.invoice_id)
  AND iv.desc='Invoice from mr. Robot'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve by below:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices
WHERE ID NOT IN (
        SELECT invoice_id
        FROM robot_calls
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM invoices 
WHERE`desc`='Invoice from mr. Robot' 
AND ID NOT IN
(SELECT invoice_id FROM robot_calls)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like that;

```
SELECT * FROM invoices where `desc`='Invoice from mr. Robot' and invoice_id NOT IN
(SELECT invoice_id FROM robot_calls)
```

Answer (score 1):

A left join should work for this:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices i
LEFT JOIN robot_calls r ON r.invoice_id=r.id
WHERE i.desc = 'Invoice from mr. Robot'
AND r.invoice_id IS NULL
```